# Dual Boot Ubuntu on a working windows 10 Asus Tuf Gaming A17 FA706IH-AU016T

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, bios, multi-boot

just now I brought an Asus Tuf Gaming (FA706IH-AU016T) with a working Windows 10 operating system.
I'm using this laptop for my Android development I just want to install Ubuntu on this one.
And I came to know the Graphics card on my laptop won't work on ubuntu.
I just want to know how to dual boot a gaming laptop and also use the Graphics card on ubuntu also.

Help me with step-by-step installation methods.
Thank you :)

Comment: Saying that something "doesn't work" without providing any specifics is a sure way to not get a helpful response, both on the Internet and in real life. What does "won't work" mean here?

Comment: My question is, can I install the normal method for dual-booting, or is there anything that needs to be done before installing Linux. I have a dedicated graphics card how can I use that in Ubuntu.